# domination originairement subie

Tags: expressions

Pouvez vous reformuler cette phrase dont je n'ai pas pu saisir le sens, surtout la partie de "domination originairement subie":

> Il s’impose déjà au plan de la compréhension de l’articulation entre le sexe et la politique, une espèce de domination de l’autre générée souvent par une domination originairement subie et susceptible de se retourner contre la société à son tour dominée

Comment: Pourrais-tu dire d'où tu tires cette citation ?

Comment: @Laure il semble que la source soit "Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique”. Georges BALANDIER [(vu sur ce post)](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/18441/7321)

Comment: On indique la provenance des citations. De plus le choix d'une « reformulation » est trop arbitraire. Voir l'[aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) qui indique ce qu'il faut éviter quand on pose une question.

Comment: C'est un rapport contenant des remarques sur une thèse de doctorat d'un chercheur marocain auteur de sujet "le sexe et la politique"

Answer (score 1):

"Domination subie" fait référence à une situation de domination, où la personne est dominée (ce n'est pas elle qui a le contrôle). Ce qui fait contraste à la personne dominante (la personne qui contrôle).

Le texte explique que quand on est dominant, c'est souvent parce qu’on a été dominé (cf "domination subie") avant (cf "originairement"), et qu'on veut prendre le contrôle que l'on a pas eu dans une situation précédante.